# how to change icon of initialize flutter_background_service?

Tags: flutter, flutter-notification, flutter-background

how to change icon of initialize flutter_background_service?

`Future initializeService() async {
final service = FlutterBackgroundService();

const AndroidNotificationChannel channel = AndroidNotificationChannel(
'my_app_id', // id
'Check out', // title
description: 'in Progress',
importance: Importance.high, //
showBadge: true,
enableVibration: true, // importance must be at low or higher level
);

final flutterLocalNotificationsPlugin = FlutterLocalNotificationsPlugin();

if (Platform.isIOS || Platform.isAndroid) {
await flutterLocalNotificationsPlugin.initialize(
const InitializationSettings(
iOS: DarwinInitializationSettings(),
android: AndroidInitializationSettings('@mipmap/ic_launcher'),
),
);

}

await flutterLocalNotificationsPlugin
.resolvePlatformSpecificImplementation()
?.createNotificationChannel(channel);

await service.configure(
androidConfiguration: AndroidConfiguration(
onStart: onStart,
autoStart: true,
isForegroundMode: true,
notificationChannelId: 'my_app_id',
initialNotificationTitle: 'Check out',
initialNotificationContent: 'In Progress . . .',
foregroundServiceNotificationId: 888,
),
iosConfiguration: IosConfiguration(
autoStart: true,
onForeground: onStart,
onBackground: onIosBackground,
),
);

service.startService();
}`

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.